# Lua string.match doesn't catch control characters

Tags: lua, match, lua-patterns

Trying to modify the code of a WoW addon: https://github.com/chocochaos/GMGenie to get more information from

The text it's something similar to this:

```
cff00ff00Ticket: 6969. cff00ff00Created by: Me cff00ff00Created: 57m32s ago cff00ff00Last change: 57m32s ago cff00ff00Ticket Message: [asd] cff00ff00Ticket Response: [answer 1
answer 2
answer3
]
```

I want to get the lines between the last brackets ([,]). This code gets only the first answer but ignores the other 2.

```
local response = string.match(arg1, "%|cff00ff00Ticket%sResponse%|r:%s%[(.*)");
```

This another code is working too: getting another vars:

```
local ticketId, name, createStr, lastModifiedStr, rest = string.match(arg1, "^%|cffaaffaaTicket%|r:%|cffaaccff%s([0-9]+).%|r%s%|cff00ff00Created%sby%|r:%|cff00ccff%s(.+)%|r%s%|cff00ff00Created%|r:%|cff00ccff%s([a-zA-Z0-9%s]+)%sago%|r%s%|cff00ff00Last%schange%|r:%|cff00ccff%s([a-zA-Z0-9%s]+)%sago%|r%s(.*)$");
```

I know the separators between lines are "\n".

I tryied to modify the (.*) pattern to add all the lines until the last bracket (]), using this:

```
local response, response2 = string.match(arg1, "%|cff00ff00Ticket%sResponse%|r:%s%\[(.*)+");
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know what is better: try to get all the characters in the same string and trim with gsub, or try to get any kind of array of strings. Could you help me?

Comment: Do you need to get them as separate strings or a single multiline string? Try `local response = string.match(arg1, ".*%[(.*)]");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trying to solve this, I found that the server was sending me one response for each line of data. You cannot match or search anything outside the response variable...

At least not before concat the 3 responses. Really hard to do because each response starts a new code execution, because that addon code is used in a class that read each server response.

I will leave this as impossible to solve without rewrite the addon from scratch or rewrite the way the server lauches the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You may match the text between last sqaure brackets using `.*%[(.*)]` and then match all lines inside the match:

```
local arg1 = "cff00ff00Ticket: 6969. cff00ff00Created by: Me cff00ff00Created: 57m32s ago cff00ff00Last change: 57m32s ago cff00ff00Ticket Message: [asd] cff00ff00Ticket Response: [answer 1\nanswer 2\nanswer3\n]"
local response = string.match(arg1, ".*%[(.*)]");
answer_lines = {}
for s in response:gmatch("[^\r\n]+") do
    table.insert(answer_lines, s)
end
```

See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/64QYDN).